# How to go back to activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-activity

Basically, I have 2 activity and 1 fragment inside one of activity. I can figure it like this,  Activity A: there a some the button to show activity (that is activity B). Activity B: frame layout (container) to show a fragment.
When a button clicked, then activity B displayed. The problem is I can’t get back to activity A to make a call again (by intent) on another button. In my code, I just can go back to activity B.
I have been tried this code but still went back in activity B

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Comment: If you have not called `finish()` on activity A while navigating to activity B, you can go back to A simply be pressing back button. `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()` will not work here.

Comment: @ShreyGarg, how can i do that? can you tell me more about that code? i'm sorry, new bie on android

Comment: Please add your code for navigation A to B and back B to A

Comment: Its only in Activity A : (navigate to activity B)
Intent itemMenu = new Intent(this,B.class);
startActivity(itemMenu);   

In activity B not yet.

Comment: Just pressing back button on activity B should navigate to activity A

Comment: Oh, forgot to tell you, activity B clearly to display the fragment. And i didn't want any button on it. So, when I clicked back button from fragment, if it can be, i want back to Activity A. Previously, it only can be back to Activity A.

Comment: Inside `onBackPressed()` of fragment, try calling `getActivity().onBackPressed()`

Comment: @ShreyGarg,  thankyou. After trying a while. Its work for me. i'm sorry, new bie, i don't know to mark as accepted answer.

Comment: I have added an answer, you can upvote/accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `onBackPressed()` of fragment, try calling `getActivity().onBackPressed()`

As you mentioned in the comments, your problem is solved now.

Comment: Yeah, its makes me feel free. Thanks a lot.